# C++ Code runs on one machine, but seg fauls on another

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a program which reads OCT Images and transform it to an Point Cloud. I compiled the program as executable to copy it to another machine. I tried to run the executable that machine and get a Seg Fault code:

```
Thread 1 "OpenCLBA-Prod" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000423ca1 in generatePointCloudFromModel(boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >&, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) ()
```

This is the message when i tried to run `gdb list`:

```
../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-procinfo.c: No such file or directory.
```

I used `backtrace`,`where` and `list` of `gdb`, but it is all the information i can find.

What could possibly the culprit here ? I looked into stackoverflow and it says it could be `undefined behavior`, but this methode is frequently used on different machines in my uni (i did not modify it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could possibly the culprit here

This is quite common: your program has undefined behavior (such as heap corruption or a data race), and "works fine" on one machine while crashing on another.

Your first step should be to run the program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and fix any errors it finds.

Your second step should be to instrument your program with Address, Memory and Thread [Sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers).

> this methode is frequently used on different machines in my uni (i did not modify it).

The problem is most likely in your own code, not in the method where the crash is happening.

Comment: I definitely should try that, but afaik, this method runs fine at at least 2 other machines, only this one it doesnt.

Comment: I have Read your edit, it seems a good way to do it, thanks for your answer !